# SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\x82'

Tags: python, eclipse

I get this error in Eclipse while working on "Byte of Python"

It says the error shows up in 2 lines:

```
source = ["C:\\My Documents", "C:\\Code"]
```

and

```
zip_command = "zip -qr {0} {1}".format(target, ‚ ‚.join(source))
```

I cant really figure out what im doing wrong here.

Here's the full error:

> SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\x82' on line x, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details

Comment: Thanks that was it. Feel kinda stupid now. Thanks a lot. Didn't even know this could cause problems.

Comment: Glad it worked, added my comment as an answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using chars (curved quotes) encoded in `windows-1252` that cannot be decoded because it's not valid `utf-8`. Replace the quotes and you are good to go.

Comment: One small question, how did you know that the chars are encoded in `windows-1252`? And your solution worked while I was working with PyQT4 :)

Comment: @PragyadityaDas Quotes are not for pre-formatted text, use code sample for that. I still accepted the edit because your intentions were good, I just improved it.