# Getting following error on generating language scorer on Deepspeech

Tags: mozilla-deepspeech, make-scorer

File "generate_scorer_package", line 1
SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xea' in file generate_scorer_package on line 2, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details

Answer (score 0):

Before answering this question, I am going to make some assumptions:

- Firstly, I believe you are following the [DeepSpeech Playbook](https://mozilla.github.io/deepspeech-playbook/) and are at the step in generating a `kenlm.scorer` file, as [documented here](https://mozilla.github.io/deepspeech-playbook/SCORER.html#generating-a-kenlmscorer-file-from-generate_scorer_package)
- Secondly, I am going to assume that you are using a Python editor of some descrition, like PyCharm.

The error `SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xea' in file generate_scorer_package on line 2, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details` is not related to DeepSpeech; it is related the Python encoding of the file that is being executed.

Python 3 assumes that the encoding of the `.py` file is `UTF-8`; however some editors - particularly editors in other locales - can override this setting.

To force the file to `UTF-8` encoding, add the following code to the top of the `generate_scorer_package.py` file:

```
# coding: utf8
```

*NOTE: It MUST be at the top of the file*

Alternatively, identify where in your editor the encoding is set, and change it.

See also these Stack Overflow questions that are similar:

- [SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\x92' in file D:\AIAssistant\build\gui.py on line 92, but no encoding declared;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70479826/syntaxerror-non-utf-8-code-starting-with-x92-in-file-d-aiassistant-build-gu)
- [SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\x82'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15602038/syntaxerror-non-utf-8-code-starting-with-x82)